# How to search in multiple java files for certain statement?

Tags: python

I am new to python. In the following code, I am trying to extract all print statements from an application directory which contains many files written in Java and xml and write them in another file (.txt). I have the following code but it doesn't work

```
import glob
import os, sys


folderpath= os.chdir("/.../.../MyApp")

for files in glob.glob('*.java'):
    with open("/.../.../result.txt", "w") as f:
        for filename in files:
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(folderpath + filename) as currentFile:
                text = currentFile.read()
                if ('print' in text):
                    f.write('Found the word in ' + filename + ' in line: ' + text + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

change (below line is not executed, just assigned)

```
folderpath= os.chdir("/.../.../MyApp")
```

to

```
os.chdir("/.../.../MyApp")
```

path undefined in this line:

```
filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
```